# Popup floating image in html frames

Tags: image, popup, frames, floating

I have a frameset containing two frames (top.html and bottom.html). I want to create a pop up floating image in the second frame (bottom) but have the script to do this in the first frame (top). Is this possible and how?

```html
<frameset id="mainFrame" rows="25%,75%"> 
   <frame id="f1" src="top.html">
   <frame id="f2" src="bottom.html">
</frameset>
```